# I need a game over (UI image) to appear after timer reaches 0

Tags: unity, c#, gui

[image]So here is my timer script that works fine. I need it to activate the game over (UI image) when the timer reaches 0.

I tried attaching a game over script to the UI image (GOS script)..... no luck

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text gametimer;
    public float timeLeft;
    public GameObject Gameover;
    public Text gameovertext;

    void Update()
    {
        if (timeLeft > 0)    
        {
            timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else  
        {
            timeLeft = 0;   
        }

        displaytime(timeLeft);    
    }

    void displaytime(float timeToDisplay)
    {
        if (timeToDisplay < 0)
        {
            timeToDisplay = 0;
            Debug.Log("Game Ova YOung!!!");                
        }

        float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay / 60);
        float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay % 60);

        gametimer.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
    }
}
```

Game over screen script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GOS : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject GameOverScreen;
    public Timer timer;
    
    void Start()
    {
        timer = GetComponent<Timer>();
        GameOverScreen.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (timer = null)
        {
            GameOverScreen.SetActive(true);
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you expect an inactive game object's Update method to be called? If so, I recommend re-reading the documentation on that point. You also have a typo, `if (timer = null)` which looks like it should be `==` instead. Do you have something destroying the timer that you have not shown us here?

Comment: Thank you for the typo correction I don't know why the editor didn't catch it. Yes I have set the UI image to be inactive and I want to go active once the timer reaches 0. No I do not intend on destroying the game object

Comment: So why are you comparing timer to null? What do you expect would cause timer to compare as equal to null? I'm trying to follow your reasoning here but it's not obvious to me.

Comment: TBH I've had to piece together several script for this game ( including this one) from various sources ( mostly youtube videos). I'm fairly new to coding as well. with that being said its been a lot of trial and error. the null reference, was a mere blind swing at a solution, in hopes that because the timer was no longer was actively counting,   it would in turn set the inactive object active. may seem silly but that's my experimental process.

Comment: there aren't any specific codes or videos too my knowledge.

Comment: You should definitely try to learn some of the basics of the C# language then. Objects do not simply become null when they've achieved their goal (the computer doesn't even know what a goal *is* unless you tell it what you want). In Unity, an object that was previously non-null will compare as equal to null only when you've manually called Destroy() on it or unloaded the scene it's in.

Answer (score 3):

> there aren't any specific codes or videos too my knowledge.

If you only look for code or videos that do *exactly* what you want to do, then you are limited to making only what has been made before. You cannot develop new games with this approach. A game developer must be able to abstract: break your problem into steps, find solutions to each step, and synthesize into a solution to your whole problem.

You want to be able to make something happen when a value reaches a certain value. It does not matter whatsoever that this thing is "show a game over screen". The logic to detect the value change and call a function in response is the same. So you can look at *any* example of triggering an action in response to a value and abstract that to something you can use in your synthesis.

One simple way to do this is with a `UnityEvent`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text readout;
    public float timeLeft;

    public UnityEvent onTimerCompleted;

    void Update()
    {
        if (timeLeft > 0f) {
            timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (timeLeft <= 0f) {
                onTimerCompleted?.Invoke();
                timeLeft = 0f;
            }

            DisplayTime(timeLeft);    
        }
    }

    void DisplayTime(float timeToDisplay)
    {
        float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay / 60);
        float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay % 60);

        readout.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
    }
}
```

[image]

This gives you a widget in the inspector just like the ones on UI Button components. You can use it to wire up any arbitrary thing (or sequence of things) you want to happen when the time hits zero.

Here I've asked it to take my Game Over Screen object, and call its `GameObject.SetActive()` method with an argument of `true` (checked box). But you could also make it call a public function on your own custom script instead. The beauty of this approach though is that you don't strictly need a second script to do the job.